# Hide SharePoint web part using javascript onclick method

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, onclick, hide

i need a little bit of help, I am trying to use JavaScript embedded in a SharePoint Content editor web part to hide specific web parts as the items are clicked, however it does not seem to work can anyone give me any hints/ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hidepart() 
var hlf = document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3");
    MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3.style.display="none";
    }
</script>
enter code here


 <a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="hidepart();return false;">Test</a>
```

Comment: One day I'll understand SharePoint's `ID` & `Class` Naming Conventions.. One day..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following code :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
function hidepart()
 {
 $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3').hide(); 
 }
</script>
enter code here
<a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="hidepart();return false;">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hidepart() {
var hlf = document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3");
hlf.style.display="none";
}
</script>
```

enter code here

```
<a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="hidepart();return false;">Test</a>
```

you misspelled function and you were not using the hlf variable correctly. This should do it

ok fixed you were missing a opening bracket too

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working like this, thank you harshini, your version also seems to work and looks a lot nicer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function hidepart1() {
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5").style.display = "none";} 
</script>

<a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="hidepart1();return false;">Test</a>
```

Thanks guys for helping me out thought I should share this with you, maybe someone else needs this