# Hide WSS 3.0 Webpart Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, web-parts, wss-3.0, dataviewwebpart

I am using WSS 3.0 in my application. I am displaying a List as a DataView Webpart. My objective here is to make this webpart visible to a selected group of individuals. As there is no option for Target Audience in WSS 3.0, I went to edit Permissions for List and gave Read permissions only to selected users. This doesn't hide the web part from the page, rather shows an Access Denied message to other users.

**Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.**

As I said, I want to hide this webpart, as in make it invisible on the web page from other users who do not have permissions to view it. As this message will be displayed only to those users who do not have permissions!, my approach is to search for the above message in the html and identify and hide the parentnode, thereby hiding the webpart.

I am not quite sure how to do this. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're in a situation where you can add additional web parts to the page and not trying to add JavaScript to the DataView Web Part directly. My suggestion won't work on a separate page if a Designer adds another view of this list.

Upload a blank .js file to your Site Assets. Add a Content Editor Web Part to your page, point it at that file. [Add JQuery from a provider](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) or host it yourself, adding the reference in your file. From there, you have 3 directions in which to work: first, explore the web part with Internet Explorer's F12 Developer Tools, keeping a particular eye on divs and tables with good unique ids, names, or classes that would solve your problem if hidden. Also keep an eye on the id of the div or table or cell or whatever that contains your access denied text. Second, (assuming you're new to JQuery) do some JQuery tutorials and then start playing with selecting the above items and, say, changing their background color. Once you have both of those, you're 90% there: (try to) select the object that would contain the access denied text, and if the innerHTML is present and equals that string, then set display:none for the div or tables to hide your web part. The third tool you have is editing the page directly with SharePoint Designer: you can toss a div with an id of your choosing around any xsl:template, which might help in your JQuery selecting.

I'm sorry I can't give you the specific code, since I'm not in a position to test it. If that changes, I'll try and give a more detailed response.

Old, misdirected answer: *Do either of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752676/change-access-denied-text-string-for-document-library-web-part) work for you? Alternatively, [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9332cbe8-fda4-48de-a397-5f42bff9bf73/sharepoint-2010-custom-access-denied-page) answer has some great resources to solve your problem. Just change the message to an empty string.*

Comment: Thanks Aron. Appreciate your quick reply. I do not want to customize/show a different error message, as suggested here. I would rather try and hide the web part from the web page.

Comment: Edit: I'm a retard today. Sorry. Yes, you're already asking how to change it via JavaScript. I'm going to update my above answer. SORRY!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Aron :D

I found the id for the webpart and hard coded it. It provided the solution, but I was hoping to programmatically fetch the id instead by searching the innerhtml, as I have more than one web parts that have to be hidden.

I found a partial solution here:
[Hide SharePoint web part using javascript onclick method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226720/hide-sharepoint-web-part-using-javascript-onclick-method)

I put a CEWP on the page and added the following script in it:

```
<script>
function hide()
{
    var content = document.getElementById("webpartID").innerHTML;
    var n = content.search("Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource");
    if(n!=-1)
    {       document.getElementById("webpartID").style.display="none";
    }
}
_spbodyonloadfunctionnames.push("hide");
</script>
```

In my case, I picked up the webpart id from the aspx page or view source for the page.